# Having trouble extracting categorical data from a set

Tags: subset, data-manipulation, extract

Hello I am new to R and am trying to figure out how to extract specific categorical data from a list of data.

I have tried the subset command but cannot seem to get it to pull out more than one category in the data set. I have tried the list command and to concotanate the data but neither have worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is one version of what I have tried:

```
 EMFSubset<-subset(MSHData,Blast.genus.ID==list("Cadophora","Inocybe"), drop=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use %in% instead of ==